# Handling Reporting Services and SharePoint Integration considering deprecation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017, ssrs, sharepoint

With one of our clients, we're currently faced with a dilemma. SQL Server Reporting Services Report Server (SharePoint mode) seems to have been deprecated, since the last version to support it is [SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-sharepoint/reporting-services-report-server-sharepoint-mode?view=sql-server-2016).

Now our client wants SharePoint integration with Reporting Services and SQL Server 2016 is currently supported, so there is the option to go that route. I just feel uneasy building something for a client with a technology that is essentially dead.

So, I've been researching on what sort of options there are going forward (SQL Server 2017 onwards). An [article by John White](https://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2016/11/future-report-integration-sharepoint/) pointed out that this is a good thing, because it allows for SSRS Native mode to be more tightly integrated into SharePoint. But his article is from the end of 2016 and points at future improvements that I'm battling to see.

Microsoft's own [SQL Stream Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/archive/blogs/sqlrsteamblog/simplifying-our-sharepoint-integration-story) addresses this issue in November 2016, with mention of three scenarios that they planned to focus on going forward. Namely: Embedding reports in SharePoint pages; Reporting on data in SharePoint lists; and Delivering reports to SharePoint libraries.

What I can find from Microsoft after that date is sparse. I only found one other article on the [SQL Server Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/archive/blogs/sqlrsteamblog/embed-paginated-reports-into-sharepoint-using-the-report-viewer-web-part) that mentions SharePoint, with the announcement of a "Report Viewer web part".

My question is, has anyone faced this dilemma before? And how what solution did you go with?
I know we can work with PowerShell scripts and create embedded reports on SharePoint, but it doesn't seem very elegant considering what "SharePoint mode" was.

*EDIT: I realise I asked a question that warrants an answer that's more of an opinion than a fact. What I am interested in, is approaching Report Server - SharePoint integration from a SQL Server 2017 and newer perspective.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now our client wants SharePoint integration with Reporting Services

If they just want to embed reports in SharePoint pages, or write reports consuming SharePoint List Data, go with a native-mode installation of SSRS or [Power BI Report Server](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/report-server/) and use the Report Viewer Web Part, or just the Web Page Web Part for embedding.

You might suggest they go with Power BI Report Server as it not only has the SSRS functionality, but also the Power BI Interactive Reports that are the successor to the old PowerView reports in SharePoint.

SSRS SharePoint mode adds the ability to deliver scheduled reports to SharePoint Lists, but there's reasonable workarounds for that in Native Mode.  And adds the ability to manage report content (reports, data sources, etc) inside SharePoint, so that's the key difference between Native and SharePoint integrated mode.  If they really need that, go with SSRS 2016.  It will be supported until July 2026.